# How to install CTAN packages after downloading from http://ctan.org/mirrors mirrors?

Tags: latex

I have download CTAN packages from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html with `wget --mirror --no-parent ctan.imsc.res.in`.
In the installation document they have mentioned `install-tl*` to install the downloaded package. But I couldn't find the `install-tl*` in the downloaded files. And the downloaded file size is about 2.73GB

Someone suggest me how to install CTAN latex packages after downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

tl might stand for the texlive distribution; it has its own packaging that contains many available also on CTAN, you may use the command `tlmgr` (here in a GNU/Linux Debian) to manage them.

it depends… some packages might give you instructions, some not. they lack a common format. some you first need to compile others you can just put into the texmf path etc.

you would need to be more specific on what package you want to install in which system and what problem this is supposed to solve. also you should knw the better place for such questions is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acrotex?lang=en provides sources (e.g. dtx, ins) to be compiled first (e.g. sty)… and then I placed into `~/texmf/tex/latex/acrotex` to have them in my path.